# Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException

Tags: laravel-8, named-routing

The error Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException pops up,

Yet, I do have this named route...

```
/* ADMIN SECTION */
Route::prefix('admin')->name('admin/')->group(function () {
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function(){
        Route::get('fill_contraband', 'ContrabandController@fillContraband');
        
        Route::get('/', function(){ return dashboard(); });
        
        Route::get('dashboard', function(){ return dashboard(); });
        
            Route::name('users.')->group(function() {
            Route::get('users', 'gameUserController@showUserList');
            Route::get('users/create', 'gameUserController@createUser');
            Route::post('users/create', 'gameUserController@handleCreateUser');
            Route::get('users/edit/{id}', 'gameUserController@editUser');
            Route::post('users/edit/{id}', 'gameUserController@handleEditUser');
            Route::get('users/delete/{id}', 'gameUserController@deleteUser');
            Route::get('users/bulk_create', 'GameUserBulkUploadController@index');
            Route::post('users/bulk_create/import', 'GameUserBulkUploadController@importGameUsers');
            Route::post('users/bulk_create/do_import', 'GameUserBulkUploadController@executeImportGameUsers');
            Route::get('users/edit_score/{id}', 'gameUserController@editScore');
            Route::post('users/edit_score/{id}', 'gameUserController@handleEditScore');
            Route::post('users/sendBulkEmail', 'gameUserController@sendBulkEmail')->name('sendBulkEmail');
        });
```

It is the last route I am using named Route 'sendBulkEmail', to refer from the view:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('sendBulkEmail') }}">
```

What do I do wrong??

Comment: Have you tried dumping the configured routes?

Comment: The routes list shows:

    `auth       |
|        | POST     | admin/users/send-bulk-email            | admin/users.sendBulkEmail | App\Http\Controllers\gameUserController@sendBulkEmail                    | `

When I change the route in the blade.pho I get the error:


    Route [admin/users.sendBulkEmail ] not defined.

Comment: users.sendBulkEmail ?

Comment: Found a silly typo...

    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('admin/users.sendBulkEmail') }}">

works now. 

Still wondering why the named route does not work...